# Using boost::shared_from_this for an object that sometimes isn't owned by shared_ptr

Tags: boost, shared-ptr, this-pointer

I want to use `shared_from_this` as follows:

```
class example;    // Forward declaration. 
void bar(boost::shared_ptr<example>);

class example : public boost::enabled_shared_from_this<example>
{
    void foo () 
    {
        bar(shared_from_this(this));
    }
};
```

My problem is that I don't want to force `example.foo()` to be called only with example objects that are owned by a shared_ptr. 
For example I want to allow the following:

```
example * p = new example;
p->foo();
```

but this seems to be an error, since p isn't owned by a `shared_ptr`. Please correct me if I'm mistaken.

In case I'm not mistaken, how can I get this over?

Comment: You sign a contract when deriving from `std::enable_shared_from_this<T>` and you break it with your example.

Comment: Could you please add an explanation?

Comment: @nijansen, actually the contract is on the `shared_from_this()` member function, so only applies when calling that, not when deriving from `enable_shared_from_this`

Comment: @JonathanWakely You're right, that was very sloppy said. I clarified that in my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My problem is that I don't want to force `example.foo()` to be called only with example objects that are owned by a shared_ptr.

How do you expect to pass a `shared_ptr` to `bar` if the object isn't owned by a `shared_ptr`?  Do you want to pass a n empty `shared_ptr`?

You could do nasty things with the aliasing constructor of `shared_ptr` but I wouldn't recommend it.

> Please correct me if I'm mistaken.

You're not mistaken, `enable_shared_from_this<T>::shared_from_this()` has a precondition that at least one `shared_ptr` owns the object.

> In case I'm not mistaken, how can I get this over?

There is no portable way to avoid that, because it's a precondition, and you must not violate preconditions, however this might "work" (for some value of work):

```
void example::foo () 
{
  shared_ptr<example> ptr;
  try {
    ptr = shared_from_this(this);
  } catch (boost::bad_weak_ptr const&) {
  }
  bar(ptr);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When deriving your class `T` from `std::enable_shared_from_this<T>`, you allow for an object that is managed by a `shared_ptr<T>` to generate additional `shared_ptr<T>` instances - so you work around the bad habit of doing

```
return std::shared_ptr<T>(this); // bad!
```

which usually leads to problems with double deletion (because the this pointer is already owned by a different `std::shared_ptr<T>`). The ownership problem displayed here is the same your current problem breaks down to:

Quoted from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this):

> A common implementation for enable_shared_from_this is to hold a weak reference (such as std::weak_ptr) to this. The constructors of std::shared_ptr can detect presence of a enable_shared_from_this base and share ownership with the existing std::shared_ptrs, instead of assuming the pointer is not managed by anyone else.

When you sign a contract, and you did (though as mentioned in the comments above not with deriving, but with using `shared_from_this()`), better keep it.

Comment: Replace `std` with `boost` in your mind when reading this - both are actually not quite the same thing, but in this field it applies for both exactly the same way

Comment: Thanks for answering. Though I didn't understand the sentence: "*Internally, the class usually holds a reference to itself (like std::weak_ptr) and when trying to access this with your manual allocation, you provoke an exception*". Could you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @Subway My wording sucked. I edited it so people who spent more time thinking about that than me could make it clearer.